# Error: Fill: selectcommand.connection property has not been

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve binary data from a database.

I got this error: "Error: Fill: selectcommand.connection property has not been". I can't locate the error.

```
Public Shared Function BinaryData(ByVal sFileName As String) As Byte()
            Dim strSql As String
            Dim binaryFile As Byte() = Nothing
            Dim dt As DataTable
            Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
            Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection
            sqlConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=wxx;Password=xx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework")
            sqlConn.Open()
            myCommand.Connection = sqlConn
            strSql = "SELECT Data  FROM tbldrive WHERE Filename = '" + sFileName + "'"
            Dim scmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, sqlConn)

            dt = DataComponent.DataTableQuery(DataComponent.SqlConn, strSql)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Try
                    binaryFile = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0).Item("Data"), Byte())
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try

            End If
            Return binaryFile
        End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've tried a few things in that code but accidentally left the remains of some attempts in there.

There are some things you could do a bit differently: as you're only after one item from the database, you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1); and when the code has finished with the SQL connection and command, they should have .Dispose() called on them - the [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement will take care of that for you even if something goes wrong. Finally, you should *always* use SQL parameters to pass parameters to an SQL query - it makes it more secure and avoids having to worry about things like apostrophes in the value.

```
Public Shared Function BinaryData(ByVal sFileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT Data FROM tbldrive WHERE Filename = @fname"
    Dim connStr = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=wxx;Password=xx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"

    Dim binaryFile As Byte() = Nothing

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {
                           .ParameterName = "@fname",
                           .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                           .Size = 255,
                           .Value = sFileName})

        conn.Open()

        Dim obj As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        If obj IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                binaryFile = DirectCast(obj, Byte())
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

        End If

    End Using

    Return binaryFile

End Function
```

(You may need to adjust the `.SqlDbType` and `.Size` parameters: they need to match the column type and size in the database. Also, you probably don't need MultipleActiveResultSets.)

Comment: I applied the code above .. the error is:Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]

Comment: @shreeya99 Which line does the error happen on? What is the type of the column `Data` in the database?

Comment: column type:varbinary (MAX). .....line: binaryFile = DirectCast(obj, Byte())

Comment: @shreeya99 What fixed it? I noticed I had missed a `)` off the part adding the parameter, then I created a database table with a VARBINARY(MAX) column and tested it as working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have two `SqlCommand` objects:

```
Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
...
myCommand.Connection = sqlConn
```

It's assigned but not used.

Then you have defined another one:

```
Dim scmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, sqlConn)
```

that is not used either.

And I don't know why you have this:

```
dt = DataComponent.DataTableQuery(DataComponent.SqlConn, strSql)
```

Do you even need a `SqlCommand` if you are not using it ?
Clean up your code by removing unused variables.